# Relevant conferences for bioacoustics?

Tags: noise, dissemination

Last week I was at a conference in Berlin entitled "**[Effects of Noise on Aquatic Life](https://an2022.org/)**". I was wondering, what other conferences are relevant to the bioacoustics community. I have listed a few below, including some which are not widely advertised. Also keen to hear about the terrestrial/aerial communities. Thanks in advance.

- **[ESOMM](https://sites.duke.edu/esomm2022/)**: Effects of Sound in the Ocean on marine mammals
- **[IBAC](https://2023.ibac.info/)**: International Bioacoustics Society conference

Comment: The ESOMM series is somewhat special, as it is more a community based workshop to bring together researchers and decision makers to discuss the latest development in the protection of marine mammals from anthropogenic sound. So far the participation was on invitation only.

Comment: I've made this post a Community Wiki because it is a 'list of X' type of question that contains enough value to avoid deletion. That being said, these types of questions are some times maintained on Meta, rather than the main site — see [an example on Japanese Language](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/756/1330).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Acoustical Society of America](https://acousticalsociety.org/asa-meetings/) has a conference two times a year, and often in conjunction with other international Acoustics groups. It's a large society and large meeting but they have a specific [Animal Bioacoustics Technical Committee](https://tcabasa.org/) and quite a thriving group of bioacousticians. Historically it has been dominated by marine mammal work but I've noticed a lot more taxon diversity over the last several years!

I will also say that they have a great [student group](https://asastudents.org/) that provides wonderful networking events specific for students at the meetings and student financial aid that is very straightforward/easy to apply for.

Comment: Special sessions for the next ASA conference are online now: https://acousticalsociety.org/asa-meetings/. If anyone is considering submitting a paper, abstracts for that meeting are due by July 25th!

Answer (score 17):

I participated at the [African Bioacoustic Community conference](https://africanbioacoustic.wixsite.com/abcommunity/events/abc-conference-2022) in 2020. It was  online with a discounted price and it was so good! Many researchers and many topics were covered. They also did some "lessons" of basic Bioacoustics for people that were knew to the field (me too). Different environments and species were taken in consideration. I really suggest it.

This year I took part to the [UKAN+ Bioacoustics Special Interest Group symposium](https://acoustics.ac.uk/ukan-monitoring-uk-biodiversity-symposium-15-16th-june/). It was an hybrid version. They covered a wide range of species/environments/areas and it was really worth it to participate. It had a focus on use of acoustics for long-term monitoring of biodiversity in the UK. Although they talked also about international projects and had some technical sessions.

Comment: I did the African Bioacoustics conference last year and agree it was really awesome! Unfortunately this year it’s only in person though (Kruger NP, South Africa)

Comment: @Carly Batist Yes, that's true. This is the reason why I can't attend it too. Thank you for adding the comment, probably was not clear from my answer

Answer (score 17):

Slightly specalized, but one option is the Workshop on Detection, Classification, Localization and Density Estimation of Marine Mammals using Passive Acoustics (DCLDE). The meetings occur every two years. The next will be in Spring 2024 in Rotterdam, The Netherlands. More info on the [previous conference's website](https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/ore/dclde/follow-up/). It's a fantastic meeting.

Comment: The dates are 2-7 June 2024. I suggest to to contact Organizers via Website www.dclde2024.com.

Comment: For those interested, the deadline for submitting abstracts is 29-Jan-2024

Answer (score 9):

The [World Forum for Acoustic Ecology](https://www.wfae.net/conference2023.html) conference typically has some bioacoustic/ecoacoustic stuff. The next conference is in Florida, USA in March 2023.

Just wrapped up (June 27-July 1, hybrid with in-person events in Cape Town, South Africa), but the [International Statistical Ecology Conference](https://www.isec2022.org/) also had some bioacoustic workshops & talks.

Answer (score 8):

There is not a huge bioacoustics group at [Ocean Sciences](https://www.aslo.org/osm2022/), but there are usually a few sessions related to passive acoustic monitoring. At past meetings there has been a lot of great programming for students, including pre-meeting workshops, mentoring opportunities, and group events.

Answer (score 8):

Some notes on DCLDE

It has its origin 2003 in Halifax, Can, to discuss techniques for Northern Right Whale protection, but moved on to  more general passive acoustic monitoring.

While intended as workshop and not being a conference, it is a great opportunity to learn about state of the art bioacoustic techniques, to discuss new ideas and most important to really connect of other researchers due to the smaller size.

Comment: See my comment to answer by @angie_zorka concerning data and web link

Answer (score 7):

Although not a conference focussed regularly on bioacoustics, there will be a session entitled "Methods and technics - Bioacoustics & Mechanics" at the [next Ento Conference](https://www.royensoc.co.uk/event/ento22/) (UK insect science meeting)

Answer (score 7):

Here’s a nice list of past conferences with ocean noise and bioacoustics themes on the International Quiet Oceans Experiment website. It includes many of those mentioned already and more.

https://www.iqoe.org/links/meetings

Answer (score 6):

Some relevant meetings are listed here:
https://www.ibac.info/other-meetings

Answer (score 6):

The [Forum Acusticum](https://www.fa2023.org/) meeting will have sessions dedicated to bioacoustics. The conference will take place in Turin, Italy from 11-15 September 2023.

Answer (score 3):

Some bat bioacoustics related conferences:

1. International Bat Research Conference (IBRC) [link](https://www.ibrc.org/)
2. German Bat Researchers Conference (TDFF) [link](http://tdff.de/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to this group and would like to share that bioacoustics is one of many topics welcome in this [invitation and call for proposals](https://www.wfae.net/conference2023.html) for the **2023 conference of the World Forum for Acoustic Ecology (WFAE)**.

My best,
Eric